# How to add a quick action colored image

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9, 3dtouch

How can I add a 3D Touch Colored Quick Action image like the Most Recent Action in Photos app?

[image: http://imgur.com/VrsOtr1]

My code doesn't seem to work

```
UIApplicationShortcutIcon *mostRecentIcon = [UIApplicationShortcutIcon iconWithTemplateImageName:@"imagename.png"];
```

Can you help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you correctly specified the template image name? If the specified image name does not correctly respond to a valid image resource in the app bundle/asset catalogs, nothing would be shown in the icon image for the quick action shortcut item.

Read the **Discussion** section in the link below to understand the usage of `iconWithTemplateImageName:`
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationshortcuticon/1623367-iconwithtemplateimagename?language=objc

Also take a look at this link to see how to manage the image asset catalogs.
http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/dev10510b1f7